# How do I tell mist not to download geth, but use the system-wide version?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, linux

I run Manjaro Linux which is based on Arch, so I have a very up-to-date system version of `geth`.

How do I tell `mist` not to download a per-user version of `geth`, but use the system-wide version instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/3078) shows there is currently no current way to prevent the download of `geth`.

The issue does provide two workarounds, the first which I have personally tried and can vouch for.